# Event Paint in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a method which drawing Fractals per the following snippet:

```cs
 public static void DrawFractal(int x, int y, int len, double angle, PaintEventArgs e,Panel panel1)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            double x1, y1;
            x1 = x + len * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);
            y1 = y + len * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), x, panel1.Height - y, (int)x1, panel1.Height - (int)y1);
            if (len > 2)
            {
                DrawFractal((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle + 30, e,panel1);
                DrawFractal((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle - 15, e,panel1);
            }

        }
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            FractalTree.DrawFractal(panel1.Width / 2, panel1.Height / 2, 80, 0, e, panel1);
        }
```

Now this method draws when the window is opened. I would like it to be drawn on button click.

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

I would also like to add the ability to stop rendering later. Therefore, I would be happy if you could suggest the idea of ​​working with handlers and events related to rendering.

[This is how it will look like][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGcC0.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQeHc.png

Comment: For example, add a `bool` class filed, assign `true` in `button2` click event to draw, assign `false` elsewhere  to not draw. Call `panel1.Invalidate();` after toggling the `bool` value. Also, use the stock `Pens.Black` instead of creating `new Pen(Color.Black)`.

Comment: So, in the `panel1_Paint` event: `if (someBoolVariable) FractalTree.DrawFractal(...);`.

Comment: @dr.null Would that be considered correct logic? It’s just that more buttons may appear in the future and making a variable for each bool seems incorrect from the point of view of design

Comment: @dr.null I would like to work somehow with handlers or events if possible, but somehow I could not find suitable examples, I saw only what you just described approximately

Comment: @dr.null The program only has a fractal drawing, I don’t have the whole architecture yet, but I’m attaching a screenshot of what I have. The bottom line is that I want to make a drop-down menu with a list of ready-made fractals and also add the ability to draw with custom settings

Comment: There will also be another absolutely block where similar logic is needed, but I have absolutely no developments. Therefore, I would still like to somehow work with classes or interfaces, but I don’t understand how this can be implemented.

Comment: But at the moment I would like to know if there is another way besides boolean logic using only this button as an example, then I could adapt it to the rest. Because, apart from the attached interface, I can’t add anything to my question yet, the project is only at the beginning of its journey. If at the moment you cannot give me a better solution, then I will apply this logic for now and in the future, if necessary, I will contact you again

Comment: @dr.null And if u need, i can send link on my gihub project

Comment: OK, paste the link to have a peek.

Comment: @dr.null https://github.com/IlyaKvashnin/RecursiveAlgorithms/tree/ilya
This is not only my project, I threw off the branch in which fractals are drawn, in another branch there is another task, they have not yet been combined

Comment: Check the link plz. 404.

Comment: @dr.null try again, sorry

Comment: @dr.null There is a problem in boolean logic, when I press start, the stop button is inactive

Comment: OK, you need `async` programming here to execute these heavy algorithms in a worker thread(s) to not freeze the UI. Kindly give me sometime to post some examples later. Little busy right now. Kharasho?

Comment: @dr.null I would be very happy if you post some examples. I will now push the changes that I made according to the logic you described above

Comment: Forget the bool thing. Won't help

Comment: @dr.null i pushed changes, now it’s looking how i want. If you need, can check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue that you have here is the cpu-bound operations. Executing this kind of lengthy-recursive routines in the UI thread freezes it until the completion of the execution. Hence clicking the `Stop` button - as you mentioned - does nothing.

To keep the UI responsive, create `Task` versions of your methods to run them in worker threads so they can be awaited to complete or canceled. I have here two examples to suggest.

**Draw Bitmap**

Draw the shapes on a `Bitmap` then draw it in the `Paint` event.

```cs
public class FractalTree
{
    public static void DrawFractal(
        Graphics g, Rectangle canvas, int x, int y, int len, double angle)
    {
        double x1 = x + len * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);
        double y1 = y + len * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);

        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, canvas.Height - y, (int)x1, canvas.Height - (int)y1);

        if (len > 2)
        {
            DrawFractal(g, canvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle + 30);
            DrawFractal(g, canvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle - 15);
            //DrawFractal(g, canvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle + 15);
            //DrawFractal(g, canvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle - 15);
        }
    }

    public static async Task DrawFractalAsync(
        Graphics g, Rectangle canvas, 
        int x, int y, int len, double angle,
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            double x1 = x + len * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);
            double y1 = y + len * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);

            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, canvas.Height - y, (int)x1, canvas.Height - (int)y1);

            if (len > 2)
            {
                await DrawFractalAsync(g, canvas, 
                    (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle + 30, token);
                await DrawFractalAsync(g, canvas, 
                    (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle - 15, token);
                //await DrawFractalAsync(g, canvas, 
                    //(int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle + 15, token);
                //await DrawFractalAsync(g, canvas, 
                    //(int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle - 15, token);
            }
        }, token);
    }
}
```

Implementation example...

```cs
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Input controls...
        cmbTemplates.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
        nudLen.ValueChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
        nudAngle.ValueChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
        nudOffsetX.ValueChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
        nudOffsetY.ValueChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
        bmp?.Dispose();
        cts?.Cancel();
        cts?.Dispose();
    }

    private void pnlCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bmp != null)
        {
            var r = pnlCanvas.ClientRectangle;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, r, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }

    private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Draw();

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts?.Cancel();
        bmp?.Dispose();
        bmp = null;
        pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
    }

    private async void Draw()
    {
        if (!btnDraw.Enabled) return;
        btnDraw.Enabled = false;

        var canvas = pnlCanvas.ClientRectangle;

        try
        {
            using (var cancelTS = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                cancelTS.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                cts = cancelTS;

                if (tcMain.SelectedTab == tpFractal)
                {
                    bmp?.Dispose();
                    bmp = null;
                    bmp = new Bitmap(canvas.Width, canvas.Height);

                    switch (cmbTemplates.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            var len = (int)nudLen.Value;
                            var angle = (double)nudAngle.Value;
                            var xo = (int)nudOffsetX.Value;
                            var yo = (int)nudOffsetY.Value;

                            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                                await FractalTree.DrawFractalAsync(g, canvas, 
                                    xo + canvas.Width / 2, yo + canvas.Height / 2,
                                    len, angle, cts.Token);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // Call another FractalTree algorithm...
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (tcMain.SelectedTab == tpPyramid)
                {
                    // Pyramid algorithms 
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Canceld...!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            btnDraw.Enabled = true;
            pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
            cts = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo

[image: SO73893159A]

**Draw the Shape**

Make the tasks calculate and return lists of structures that define the shapes and pass them to the relevant `Graphics.Draw...` or `Graphics.Fill...` methods.

```cs
public class FractalTree
{
    public static void GetFractalPoints(Rectangle camvas, 
        int x, int y, int len, double angle, List<List<Point>> lines)
    {
        double x1 = x + len * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);
        double y1 = y + len * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);

        var pt1 = new Point(x, camvas.Height - y);
        var pt2 = new Point((int)x1, camvas.Height - (int)y1);

        lines.Add(new List<Point> { pt1, pt2 });

        if (len > 2)
        {
            GetFractalPoints(camvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle + 30, lines);
            GetFractalPoints(camvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle - 15, lines);
            //GetFractalPoints(camvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle + 15, lines);
            //GetFractalPoints(camvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)(len / 1.5), angle - 15, lines);
        }
    }

    public static async Task GetFractalPointsAsync(
        Rectangle camvas, int x, int y, int len, double angle, 
        List<List<Point>> lines,
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            double x1 = x + len * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);
            double y1 = y + len * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360.0);

            var pt1 = new Point(x, camvas.Height - y);
            var pt2 = new Point((int)x1, camvas.Height - (int)y1);

            lines.Add(new List<Point> { pt1, pt2 });

            if (len > 2)
            {
                await GetFractalPointsAsync(camvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, 
                    (int)(len / 1.5), angle + 30, lines, token);
                await GetFractalPointsAsync(camvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, 
                    (int)(len / 1.5), angle - 15, lines, token);
                await GetFractalPointsAsync(camvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, 
                    (int)(len / 1.5), angle + 15, lines, token);
                //await GetFractalPointsAsync(camvas, (int)x1, (int)y1, 
                //    (int)(len / 1.5), angle - 15, lines, token);
            }
        }, token);
    }
}
```

... and edit the implementation example as follows...

```cs
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private readonly List<List<Point>> lines = new List<List<Point>>();

    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cmbTemplates.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
        nudLen.ValueChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
        nudAngle.ValueChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
        nudOffsetX.ValueChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
        nudOffsetY.ValueChanged += (s, e) => Draw();
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
        cts?.Cancel();
        cts?.Dispose();
    }

    private void pnlCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var line in lines.Where(l => l.Count == 2).ToList())
            e.Graphics.DrawCurve(Pens.Black, line.ToArray());
    }

    private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Draw();

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts?.Cancel();
        lines.Clear();
        pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
    }

    private async void Draw()
    {
        if (!btnDraw.Enabled) return;
        btnDraw.Enabled = false;
        lines.Clear();

        var canvas = pnlCanvas.ClientRectangle;

        try
        {
            using (var cancelTS = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                cancelTS.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                cts = cancelTS;

                if (tcMain.SelectedTab == tpFractal)
                {
                    switch (cmbTemplates.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            var len = (int)nudLen.Value;
                            var angle = (double)nudAngle.Value;
                            var xo = (int)nudOffsetX.Value;
                            var yo = (int)nudOffsetY.Value;

                            await FractalTree.GetFractalPointsAsync(canvas, 
                                xo + canvas.Width / 2, yo + canvas.Height / 2, 
                                len, angle, lines, cts.Token);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // Call another FractalTree algorithm...
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (tcMain.SelectedTab == tpPyramid)
                {
                    // Pyramid algorithms 
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Canceld...!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            btnDraw.Enabled = true;
            pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
            cts = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces some nice and simple animation:

[image: SO73893159B]